# Arduino WiFly run web_app not found?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to setup an Arduino to setup an access point to configure SSID and password for connecting to a Wi-Fi network.

I got it working clean when I have the credentials hard coded, but getting it to accept credentials is proving difficult.

I am running a [WiFly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954) shield with rn171 updated firmware to 4.00.

According to the user manual for rn171, sending the command "run web_app\r"
should run some pre-configured script within the chip to create an access point and allow submitting values for network access.

The trick is that when I submit "run web_app" it gives me "web_app not found".

Alternatively I've tried running it as an access point / web-server -- so far a no-go.

I tried goding through telnet for a bit and updated firmware again just in case. 
The statements below were run in CMD mode, followed by the action/response.

```
 - wps = run wps scan & reboot 
 - run wps = run wps scan & reboot 
 - web_app = ERR: ?-Cmd 
 - run web_app = web_app not Found 
 - run web = web not Found
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the command "ftp update wilfy7-400.mif" to get the applications which include web_app.